# How to apply horizontal smooth scrolling to (example included) JQuery website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scroll, smoothing

A very generous Stack Overflow user helped me with the following drag horizontal navigation (seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/eT5MM/2/) and I'm now trying to implement the JQuery smooth horizontal scrolling as an additional form of navigation, should a user be on a mobile device: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Unfortunately, my reference links aren't working properly, and I'm not sure if there is conflicting JavaScript, or something different. The website is not currently live, so unfortunately I'm unable to share that code, however it is nearly exactly the same as the above JSFiddle code, and I'm using

```
<a name="Name">
```

and

```
<a href="#Name">
```

to navigate the page.

Thank you!
A

Comment: Hello, you want on a href click to scroll to each panel? or you are loading diferent html pages?

Comment: Hi again, Pluda. I'm hoping for them to scroll to each panel. I've tried the jquery link above, and then just the simple ref tag, but haven't been able to get it to properly scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the same code of previous question, here is the clickable scrolling menu

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TguXM/)